# list tail pattern matching in erlang

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

Suppose I have two lists:

```
First = [1,2,3,4].
Second = [1,2,3,4,234242].
```

I know that all elements of the second list match the elements of the first list, with exception of the last extra element. How can I use pattern matching to get the last one?

Comment: Given the way lists are defined, we can not match a pattern against the last element in a list.

Answer (score 7):

You could write a function that recurses down both lists as long as the elements are equal, and then returns the last element of the second list once the first list is empty:

```
find_tail([Head | Tail1], [Head | Tail2]) ->
    find_tail(Tail1, Tail2);
find_tail([], [Last]) ->
    Last.
```

---

You could do it with plain pattern matching only if the first list is a literal constant:

```
1> [1,2,3,4] ++ [Last] = [1,2,3,4,234242].
[1,2,3,4,234242]
2> Last.
234242
```

But you can't do it if it is a variable:

```
3> X = [1,2,3,4].
[1,2,3,4]
4> X ++ [Last] = [1,2,3,4,234242].
* 1: illegal pattern
```

Comment: I want to do it without function call. Just by pattern matching. Suppose the extra item was at the head of my list. Then I could write:
[TheItem | First ] = Second.

Comment: @MehdiPourfar, As `Robert K` mentioned, you cannot pattern match the last element of a list unless you enumerate all the previous elements in the pattern, e.g. `[_,_,_,_,Last] = Second.`

Comment: I updated my answer with a pattern matching example - does that make more sense?